# Java doesn't break a while when runs in Linux

Tags: java, linux, while-loop

I found a mysterious problem with a Java code for homework. A friend program an application which this at the beginning :

```
public void run() {
    vm.setVisible(true);
    while(!end);
    System.out.println("Finish");
    vm.setVisible(false);
}
```

The boolean 'end' is false while all the execution and when the user quits the application this happens:

```
private class CloseSys implements ActionListener {
    public CloseSys() {super();}

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("CLOSE SYS");
        System.out.println("end: "+end);
        end = true;
        System.out.println("end: "+end);
    }
}
```

The println shows like the value of 'end' changes to true and logically in my friend's computer (MacOS) the while finish and the application too.

The problem is that in my computer (Ubuntu Linux) the println also shows like the value changes but the while doesn't ends (the "Finish" println is never reached). The funny thing about it is if we put prints into the while... then works!

Comment: Note you shouldn't use Swing (or in practice AWT) off the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`end` must be `volatile` since its shared between two threads!

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem :) I mark you as solved because I think you were the first answer. I don't know if it is the way of do it.

Comment: I was the first by about 17 seconds, but that's fair ehough ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Several other people have mentioned that it should be volatile.  One thing nobody seems to have mentioned yet is that you are "busy waiting", which is wrong, wrong, wrongity wrong.  If you want to wait for something to happen in another thread, you should use synchronization locks or [Semaphores](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try to make the `end` variable volatile - you've been bitten by a multithreading issue (and you have a multi-core CPU).

Here's some info on that: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_when.shtml

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a threading issue.

Try declaring `end` as `volatile`, or better still use a `CountDownLatch` as this avoids hogging a CPU:

```
private CountDownLatch latch;

public void run() {
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                vm.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        try {
            latch.await();
            System.out.println("Finish");
        } finally {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    vm.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Interrupt");
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

private class CloseSys implements ActionListener {    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("CLOSE SYS");
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Note the use of `invokeAndWait` to change the window visibility from a non-EDT thread.

Comment: Why the need for a CountDownLatch? Why not just Object.wait()?

Comment: The volatile works, and unfortunately I don't have time now to try the CountDownLatch, but I will try it soon.

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov, `Object.wait` is a low-level method and has pitfalls, e.g. `notify`-vs-`notifyAll`, spurious wakeup.  You can work around it but then you would be reinventing the wheel.